# How do i render dynamic partials with express-hadlebars

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

I'm trying to load my blog posts dynamically through the id passed as an argument.
This is my route

```
router.get('/blog/:id', (req, res)=>{
    const post_slug = req.params.id
    const locals ={ base__attr: "../"}

    res.render('pages/post', {locals, post_slug})

})
```

My partials are in this folder:

```
├── app.js
├── routes
└── views
    ├── home.hbs
    ├── post.hbs
    └── blog_posts
        └── 4556777654ffbfb.hbs
        └── 4556777654ffbfd.hbs
        └── 4556777654ffbfa.hbs
```

and below what I want to do in my post.hbs

```
{{ include my post file here through the slug}}
```

I've already seen a similar post on stackoverflow and another topic in the official handlebars documentation but I'm having trouble applying it because I'm a beginner on handlebars.

Comment: What does `post_slug` look like? Would `4556777654ffbfb` be an example?